# MySQL create view error

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my statement for create view and related error message, using MySQL/MySQL WorkBench. I tried the select -- from -- where works. Any hints are appreciated. :)

```
CREATE VIEW [Products Above Average Price] AS            
SELECT ProductName,Price
FROM Products
WHERE Price>(SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products)
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Products Above Average Price] AS             #how to? SELECT ProductName,Price ' at line 1

Comment: MySQL uses back-ticks instead of [].

Comment: Works for me, thanks @jarlh. If you could have a formal answer, I can help to mark as answer to benefit other people met with the same issue as well. :)

Comment: There's already a helpful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use *ANSI standard* double quotes `""` instead of `[]` brackets.

```
CREATE VIEW "Products Above Average Price" AS 
SELECT ProductName,Price
FROM Products
WHERE Price>(SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how view creation is supposed to look like in MySQL

```
Create View `MyViewName` as 
    Select
        col1, col2, col3
    From
        myTable T
```

In your case, the problem occures because of `[]` which aren't used in MySQL. Replace your query with

```
CREATE VIEW `Products Above Average Price` AS            
    SELECT ProductName,Price
    FROM Products
    WHERE Price>(SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Copied comment)
ANSI SQL has double quotes (`""`) for delimited identifiers, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW "Products Above Average Price" AS...
```

MS SQL Server also has `[]` as a vendor specific way to delimit identifiers, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW [Products Above Average Price] AS...
```

MySQL has back-ticks, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW `Products Above Average Price` AS...
```